# How to convert a list in [ ] format to ( ) format

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large dataframe with a few hundred million records. I only want 10% of the df so i am filtering the df while reading it. The filter condition is dynamic and changes from one experiment to another.

There is another df from which i am getting the filter values:

```
filter = "filter_condition in" + tuple(df1.select("xxx").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())
```

The above snippet gives a list say for example `[1]`

I am using the below query to read the large file:

```
large_df = (sqlContext.read.parquet(path).filter(filter))
```

When the tuple has more than 1 element the query works fine but when the filter condition has only 1 value then the tuple comes out as (1,) or (10293,) etc. and this causes an error while reading the large df since the filter condition comes out to be

```
(sqlContext.read.parquet(path).filter("filter_condition in (1,)"))
```

Is there a way to convert the list [1] to (1) format. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be like that as one element in brackets is just parsed as brackets, and you need the comma to make a one item tuple.

You can solve this by making a custom stringifying method:

```
def tuple_to_str(t):
    t = tuple(t)
    if len(t) == 1:
        return '({!r})'.format(t[0])
    return repr(t)
```

And doing:

```
filter = "filter_condition in" + tuple_to_str(
    df1.select("xxx").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Your approach works. Appreciate the help.